# How to show two data series of same range but different frequencies on same graph in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to show two data series (as lines) on the same graph in Excel. The two data series have different frequencies but are of approximately the same time range. To be specific, I want to overlay quarterly data with daily data.

I have gotten around this before by making the quarterly data have the same amount of observations as the daily data via copy/paste... a brutal and inelegant solution!

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? I assume the dates are along the horizontal axis? Where exactly are you running into problems?

Comment: @PFitz I'm running into problems having both the data sets present in full *and* over the full length of the x-axis. If that isn't clear I can put up a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart tool -> Change Chart Type -> Combo -> Select line and enable secondary axis

Answer (score 3):

If you use a line chart, the X values will be treated as categories that are stacked next to each other and the dates are just labels, so the two series won't be aligned.  If you want the X axis treated as a timeline, use a scatter chart (also called XY chart).  The dates will need to be stored as Excel dates rather than text.  There is no need to change the data (number of values).